# Windows IoT Core and app PFX certificate expire

Tags: pfx, windows-10-iot-core

I deployed an UWP app on Raspberry with Windows IoT Core.
What will happen when the temporary PFX certificate expire?
the app can still to run on device as the default/startup App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff369721.aspx

**What do I do if my certificate has expired**?

*So you have already deployed your application, and now your certificate (purchased or unpurchased) has expired, and you’ve examined the flowchart and determined that your customers are going to have to uninstall and reinstall the application. You can’t even issue an update. Visual Studio will not let you deploy your application with an expired certificate. So what do you do now? 
If you need to extend an existing certificate, you can use a program called RenewCert. For details, you can check out my blog post How to extend an existing certificate, even if it has expired. 
You can also find a version of RenewCert code on MSDN. I have not tested that specific version, but I’ve heard that it works with test certificates but not purchased certificates. Here’s the link if you want to check it out: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925521
If you are already using a test certificate, extending it solves your problem. You can sign your deployment with the extended certificate, issue updates, and it will work fine. You can go to lunch, and the rest of us with known publishers can eat at our desks while we continue on. (Can you bring something back for us?)
If you are using a purchased certificate and it has expired, you can use an extended certificate to sign and deploy an update to your application, but it will look like a test certificate. This will seem just like any other update to your customer who already has the application installed, because it does not show the trust dialog when installing an update. New customers will see “Unknown Publisher” in the trust dialog because you are now using a test certificate.
So if your purchased certificate has expired, this enables you to issue an update to the application that programmatically uninstalls the current version and installs a new version signed with the new purchased certificate.*

Comment: but the app already deployed (unless it is uninstalled) will continue to run even when its PFX certificate expires, or not?